# Commandline chat for Gmail chat in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, gmail, chat

Is there any tool for having gmail chat/Hangouts in my mac osx terminal? Googled a lot but couldnt find a reliable one that works for mac osx; most of them are for linux os.

Answer (score 1):

`finch` should suit your neds. It's ncurses based and connects to gchat through XMPP.

`brew install finch`

https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/use-fbgtalk-chat-using-terminal-console/12/07/2013/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty. 
The one worth mentioning is ['hangups'](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups), although it is under rapid development, but still great replacement for hangouts(as finch or Profanity support only old style xabber/googletalk[no offline chats/hangouts]).